# no rule to make target. whats this?

Tags: c++, eigen3

```
No rule to make target /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../Plugins/CommonCwiseUnaryOps.h', needed by block_grasp_generator-hydro-devel/CMakeFiles/block_grasp_generator_visualization_tools.dir/src/visualization_tools.cpp.o'. Stop.

the file "CommonCwiseUnaryOps.h" exists in "/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/plugins"

eigen_conversionsConfig-version.cmake is in /opt/ros/hydro/share/eigen_conversions/cmake

eigen_conversionsConfig.cmake is in /opt/ros/hydro/share/eigen_conversions/cmake
```

What should I do?

another question is what does the path `"/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../Plugins/"` mean and what do the 2 dots imply?

Answer (score 4):

The 2 dots mean `go to the parent directory`, so

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../Plugins/
```

means go to

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Plugins/
```

Notice that `Plugins` is capitalized, whereas your file is in `plugins`, lowercase

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/plugins
```